# Touchpad drivers worked in 16.04 and don't work on 18.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, upgrade, 18.04, touchpad

If I enter the `xinput --list` command into a terminal I get the following output.

```
Virtual core pointer          id=2
  Virtual core XTEST pointer  id=4
  Synaptics TM3096-006        id=11
  SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad  id=15
```

These drivers worked fine with `Ubuntu 16.04`. I did a clean install of `Ubuntu 18.04` and the touchpad sucks now. The mouse pointer randomly accelerates and decelerates. It's very erratic and jumps and hops around the screen.

Am I left to re-write the driver myself? What should I do? No clue.

**[EDIT]** I did not install any drivers on `16.04` or `18.04`. Yet something has broken between the two versions. The touchpad worked fine on `16.04`, now it doesn't on `18.04`. I assume this is a driver issue (`Synaptics TM3096-006` driver or the `SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad` driver shown above).

Comment: Which "drivers" are you talking about?

Comment: Did you install any drivers? It is not clear.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited original post to try and clarify. Hope that helps.

Comment: Now it is clear. Most likely it is a kernel regression. Or it may be a conflict between two modules. There should not be two touchpad input devices normally.

Comment: @Pilot6 if it is kernel regression what should I do?

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing *xserver-xorg-input-synaptics* ended up fixing the problem

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`